# Nuget Install - .net core - All assemblies in lib directory are not added as references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

As part of a project, I've created a nuget package (targeting .net core 3.1) that has multiple assemblies in the final 'lib' directory. Although .net core advocates creating a separate nuget package for each referenced project, I've followed a workaround mentioned [here](https://dev.to/wabbbit/include-both-nuget-package-references-and-project-reference-dll-using-dotnet-pack-2d8p). But when I try to consume this nuget in another simple console project, I do not see all the DLLs that are present in the lib directory referenced in the "Compile Time Assemblies", only one of them is listed in the Compile Time assemblies. Am I missing anything here. ? Appreciate any help

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you haven't given enough information for me to investigate. I don't want to read the blog post you linked, create multiple projects and test the generated package. Maybe I'm too lazy, but if it takes me more than 60 seconds to investigate, I'm less likely to. Also, maybe it'll "just work" for me, then I'll have no idea why it's not working for you. If you follow StackOverflow's suggestion, it'll be much, much easier for people to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Given NuGet works by convention based on file paths/names in the package, telling us the file list in the nupkg is probably enough to answer your question. Even the blog post doesn't show the generated nupkg's file list.

Comment: Hi Naren, any update about your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your main nuget project has many referenced assembly dlls under **Dependencies**-->**Assemblies**, it will not be added into the nuget package by your function since it is  very fragile.

You have to repack them all. Just add these node in the `csproj` file additionally.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(TargetDir)\*.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
</ItemGroup>
```

This is my whole `csproj` file which packs all the dlls into the `Lib` folder from referenced assembly dlls and project references.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\testtt\testtt.csproj">
          <ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
          <IncludeAssets>testtt.dll</IncludeAssets>
        
      </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="testr" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)">
      <HintPath>..\..\testr\testr\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\testr.dll</HintPath> 
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
        <ItemGroup>
            <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths-&gt;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(TargetDir)\*.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Note**: when you install the new release version into another project, please first delete all nuget caches which exists your old wrong version under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages` or [use this way to clean the nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).